# Knockout click binding not working when hiding the element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, focus

I have the simplified code as follows. What I am trying to do is to update the input box with the value clicked from the below UL LI list and then hide the list.

```
<input data-bind="value: Name, hasfocus: isSelected" />
<ul data-bind="foreach: NameList, visible: isSelected">
    <li data-bind="text: $data, click: function () { $root.Name($data); }"></li>
</ul>
```

View model

```
  function VM()
    {
        var self = this;
        self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
        self.Name = ko.observable();
        self.NameList = ko.observableArray();
        self.NameList.push("A");
        self.NameList.push("B");
        self.NameList.push("C");
        self.NameList.push("D");
        self.NameList.push("E");
        self.NameList.push("F");
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

It works unless I try to hide the UL on focusout. (Remove **visible: isSelected** in UL to see it works)

One solution is that I can hide the UI after click of the li but what I really want is the list gets closed even when user does not select any value from the list. Similar to the behavior of a dropdown but I cannot use dropdown menu for some styling reason.

Also I cannot use libraries like bootstrap or JQueryUI

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5x9fr/)

Comment: I assume there is a reason why you can't just use a drop down list?

Comment: Yes. First problem is that it is difficult to style (Without using JavaScript plugins) and make it look like the same in different browsers. Apart from that there is a problem with binding while using dropdown (May be it deserves a separate question)

Comment: fair enough, have posted another solution below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. I'm adding a second observable, and introducing a delay when `isSelected` is changed to `false`

```
self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
self.isVisible = ko.observable(false);

self.isSelected.subscribe(function(val) {
  if (val) {
    self.isVisible(true);
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.isVisible(false);
    }, 300);
  }
});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sabof/u756m/)

---

The above has the disadvantage that `mouseup` needs to happend within the time limit. An alternative is to bind to `mousedown`, instead of `click`

```
<li data-bind="text: $data, event: {mousedown: function () { $root.Name($data); }}"></li>
```

Comment: Thanks @sabof.I have improved it a bit with self.isSelected = ko.observable(false).extend({ throttle: 300 }); which does the same thing without requiring a new property. I will accept it as answer if I don't get a better solution